# jQuery delegate object instead of selector as first argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is is possible to pass an object instead of a selector as the first argument for jQuery delegate?

```
var ancestor = $('ancestor'),
    children = ancestor.find('a');

ancestor.delegate(children, eventType, handler);
```

Instead of the regular:

```
ancestor.delegate('a', eventType, handler);
```

**EDIT**

Motivation:

```
var children = $('a[href^="#"]').map($.proxy(function(i, current) {

    var href = $(current).attr('href');

    if(href.length > 1 && givenElement.find(href).length === 1) return $(current);
},
this));

$(document).delegate(children, eventType, handler);
```

I want to delegate only the anchor elements that are hash linked to any element as a child of a given element. Basically I want to do something you can't do with just a selector only.

Comment: What is your motivation for doing this? Could you elaborate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just set up the delegation and then do your predicate *inside* the event handler:

```
ancestor.delegate('a[href^="#"]', 'click', function(ev) {
  if (someElement.find($(ev.target).attr('href')).length > 0) {
    // do whatever with ev.target
  }
});
```

If you wanted to avoid the runtime price of doing that jQuery DOM search inside the handler, you could pre-tag all the "good" tags:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').each(function() {
  if (someElement.find($(this).attr('href')).length > 0)
    $(this).addClass("special");
});
```

Then your delegated event handler can just check

```
  if ($(ev.target).hasClass('special')) {
    // do stuff
  }
```

which will perform well enough to not be a problem under any circumstances.

The reason you have to start with a selector for ".delegate()" to work is that that's the way it's implemented. The event handler always does something like:

```
  function genericDelegateHandler(ev) {
    if ($(ev.target).is(theSelector)) {
      userHandler.call(this, ev);
    }
  }
```

Now, clearly it *could* also try and compare the actual elements in the case that you set up a delegate without a selector, but it just doesn't.

*edit* — @DADU (the OP) correctly points out that if you go to the trouble to mark everything with a class name, then you don't even need a fancy event handler that tests; an ordinary ".delegate()" will do it. :-)

Comment: Thought about it but that's not really efficient since there would be a bubble up for every hash link. If there is no other way I will stick with this though.

Comment: Bubbling an event up the DOM is not very expensive unless your DOM is enormously deep, since most parent elements won't have any registered handlers.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yes but only when you bind or delegate them, not? So if you leave them out of the delegation, there is no function call for nothing.

Comment: @Pointy You have to use `$(ev.target).attr('href')` since `ev.target.href` returns the fully qualified URL which cannot be used as a selector.

Comment: By the way, is it not possible to pass an object because jQuery doesn't handle it or because it is not possible with plain JavaScript?

Comment: @DADU Click events bubble up the entire DOM tree regardless of whether or not you've bound any handlers.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Okay. Don't know so much about bubbling yet apparently. Thanks!

Comment: @Pointy thanks for your update! That's the way to go. With your solution of adding a classname, you don't even have to check with `hasClass`, you can just set a delegate selector of `a[href^="#"].special`.